# The android arrayadapter has problems with if validating large information

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have the problem with an adapter, which receives an information arraylist from a payment status, which comes with an "AT" status, when it is worth to paint it of a specific color, the android paints that state and other states that In the "AT"
Without any query. I validate it with equals but it seems that it malograra the android and validates others that are not "AT".

```
public class PlanPagosCreditoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<beanDatosPlanPagosCredito> {

public List<beanDatosPlanPagosCredito> list;

public PlanPagosCreditoAdapter(Context context, List<beanDatosPlanPagosCredito> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    list = objects;
}

@Override
public beanDatosPlanPagosCredito getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Obtener inflater.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.lista_detalle_creditos,
                parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.fecha_cuota = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_cuota);
        holder.num_cuota = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.num_cuota);
        holder.deuda = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deuda);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder= (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    beanDatosPlanPagosCredito credito = getItem(position);

    holder.fecha_cuota.setText(credito.getFechaCuota());
    holder.num_cuota.setText(credito.getNumeroCuota());
    DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    // subtotal.setText(precision.format(deuda));
    holder.deuda.setText(precision.format(credito.getDeuda()));

    if(credito.getEstado().equals("AT")){
        holder.deuda.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {

    TextView fecha_cuota;
    TextView num_cuota;
    TextView deuda;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your views are being recycled and they are staying red. Add an else clause where you reset the text color:

```
if(credito.getEstado().equals("AT")){
    holder.deuda.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    holder.deuda.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: @LuisAlexanderManriqueLopez,  if this solution worked for you can you accept it as the answer?